# Get all Schema.org html tags with php?

Tags: php, domdocument

Schema.org have HTML tags, these tags follows the following pattern: `itemscope itemtype=""` and `itemprop=""`.

These tags are inserted into other HTML tags such as a `div`, `span`, `body`, `and others`.

All I would do is look for these tags in a particular page and put them in an array. Example:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">StackOverflow</div>
<span itemprop="name">Stack</span>
```

In this case, if found one of these tags: `itemscope itemtype=""` or `itemprop=""` the code will select all the plot where this marking is, example: If found that tag inside a `div`, the code will save all the `div` and the content inside it, example:

```
 '0' = '<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">StackOverflow</div>' ,
 '1' = '<span itemprop="name">Stack</span>'
```

So far I have only this code:

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://stackoverflow.com');
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML($html);
```

How I can do this?

Comment: have a look at `DOMXPath::query` here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php